# Aligning integers(Basic python)

Tags: python

Hey guys I need some help aligning my integers. I will show you what my code is, what my output is, and what I want my output to be. Thanks!

Code:

```
test_sign='#'
test_numbers=[100000,5000000,7000000]
test_calc_list=[]
test_sum=sum(test_numbers)
test_list=['Testcase1','Testcase2','Testcase3']
test_sign_list=[]

for x in test_numbers:
    test_calc=round((x/float(test_sum)*10))
    test_calc_list.append(test_calc)

for y in test_calc_list:
    y=int(y)
    signs=y*test_sign
    test_sign_list.append(signs)

for z in range(len(test_list)):
    print "%8s"%test_list[z]+":",test_sign_list[z],test_numbers[z]
```

Output:

```
Testcase1:  100000
Testcase2: #### 5000000
Testcase3: ###### 7000000
```

Desired output:

```
Testcase1:         100000
Testcase2: ####   5000000
Testcase3: ###### 7000000
```

Comment: As a side note, instead of `for z in range(len(test_list)):` and a complicated expression with `test_list[z]`, `test_sign_list[z]`, `test_numbers[z]`, try `for test, sign, number in zip(test_list, test_sign_list, test_numbers):`, then a simpler expression with `test`, `sign`, and `number`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option one, specify length in format:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

"width is a decimal integer defining the minimum field width. If not specified, then the field width will be determined by the content."

Option two, pre-pad strings using ljust, rjust and center:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust

Comment: Specifically something like `"{0:8}: {1:>10d} {2:>10d}".format(case_name, one_number, another_number)` would produce 8-char wide column for case name and two 10-char wide right-aligned columns for two numbers.

Comment: @9000: I know you took that `{0:8}` from the OP's `%8s`… but if you look at it, his strings are all 9 characters wide, so you probably don't want that (and he probably didn't want the `8` in his original code, either)…

Answer (score 5):

This might be a good time to learn `{}`-formatting, instead of learning more in-depth about the (not-quite-deprecated, but discouraged) `%`-formatting.

Especially since the only `%`-formatting you're using seems to be incorrect. (There's no good reason to use `%8s` for a string you know is going to be 9 characters long…)

So:

```
print '{}: {:<6} {:>7}'.format(test_list[z], test_sign_list[z], test_numbers[z])
```

See [String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) for details on all the options.

---

As a side note, I think your loop would be more readable this way:

```
for test, sign, number in zip(test_list, test_sign_list, test_numbers):
    print '{}: {:<6} {:>7}'.format(test, sign, number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
print "%8s"%test_list[z]+":",test_sign_list[z],test_numbers[z]
```

to

```
print "%8s: %-6s %7i" % (test_list[z], test_sign_list[z], test_numbers[z])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = ["abc", "sakjfslkdfnds", "7"]
maxlength = max(map(len, strings))
for index, string in enumerate(strings):
  print("Testcase%d: %s" % (index, string.rjust(maxlength, ".")))
```

Leave out the "." argument if you just want spaces.